# Bad version error in jvm , offset 6 , with Apache Cxf Soap Web service

Tags: apache, websphere, cxf

Can anybody please help me with this issue and provide me the solution because I can't even figure out what kind of error it was with Apache Cxf or webservice call or java version number or web sphere 8.5.5?

I'm using **Apache cxf 2.7.8** version to publish a **Soap web service** with **web sphere 8.5.5 version** and java 7.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: **JVMCFRE003 bad major version;** class=com/fd/foundation/frameworks/mybaitis/helloWorld/resource/MessageServiceImpl, **offset=6**
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:540)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:79)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1038)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:362)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:429)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:703)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:682)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:665)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenOptions.getClass(WsgenOptions.java:299)
```

when I check **my logs in the websphere 8.5.5** after installing the application I got the below error ?

```
[7/1/14 0:23:47:890 CDT] 00000043 SystemErr     R java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/pc-appext.jar
[7/1/14 0:23:47:905 CDT] 00000043 SystemErr     R   at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2821)
[7/1/14 0:23:47:905 CDT] 00000043 SystemErr     R   at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2994)
[7/1/14 0:23:47:905 CDT] 00000043 SystemErr     R   at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3078)
[7/1/14 0:23:47:906 CDT] 00000043 SystemErr     R   at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3026)
[7/1/14 0:23:47:906 CDT] 00000043 SystemErr     R   at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
[7/1/14 0:23:47:906 CDT] 00000043 SystemErr     R   at java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:930)
[7/1/14 0:23:47:906 CDT] 00000043 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.wkplc.extensionregistry.RegistryLoader.canonicalizeFileURL(RegistryLoader.java:671
```

)

**Below is my web service implementation class looks like ;**

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.fd.foundation.frameworks.mybaitis.helloWorld.resource.MessageServices",serviceName ="messageService")
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageServices {
    public MessageVO getMessage(Integer id) {
    MessageService message = new MessageService();
    MessageVO mvo = message.getUserDetails1(101); 
    return mvo;
    }
```

This my service interface looks like :

```
@WebService
public interface MessageServices{
    @WebMethod
    public  MessageVO getMessage(Integer id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you are running on Java 6 instead of 7 and code is compiled with Java7

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Check in the SystemOut.log, if server correctly starts with Java v7:

```
************ Start Display Current Environment ************
WebSphere [IBMJAVA7 7.0.5.0 cf011340.01]Platform 8.5.5.1 [BASE 8.5.5.1 cf011341.03] running with process name node02Cell\node02\server1 and process id 2920
Host Operating System is Windows Server 2003, version 5.2
Java version = 1.7.0, Java Compiler = j9jit26, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
was.install.root = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85
user.install.root = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\profiles\AppSrv1
Java Home = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\java_1.7_32\jre
```

Comment: hi , 
thanks for your quick reply , 
i also tried , changing the Jdk version to 7(sun but not ibm) , then i am not able to Start the web sphere server 8.5.5. 

    error from server : unable to create the java virtual machine.

Comment: You need to download and install IBM Java v7. Oracle SDK can only be used with Liberty profile not full WebSphere Application Server.